# Table calculation by awk depends on first column

Tags: awk

I have this table

```
0     56   56  
0     45  100
0      70   80
60     90   90
0      100  200
0.1    200 300
```

On this table I would like to calculate the value of `col2` and `col3` by 
`awk` depend on `col1` value: if `col1 < 60` start to calculate `col2` and 
`col3` value if `col1 >= 60`, stop and start new calculation and put the values on new col lets say `col4` and `col5`.

---

<sup>*Restated, based on [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520194/table-calculation-by-awk-depends-on-first-column#comment72177733_42520194) and [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520194/table-calculation-by-awk-depends-on-first-column#comment72177870_42520194):*</sup>

For rows where the value in column 1 is less than 60, the values in columns 2 and 3 should be added to separate sums.  When the row has a value of 60 or more in column 1, print the sums for columns 2 and 3 and re-zero the sums, then print the row read in. At the end of the input, print the remaining sums for columns 2 and 3.

---

Can any one please could help me with this?

Output looks like

```
col4   col5
171    236              first calc
60     90               stop
300    500              sec calc
```

Comment: can you modify your desired output with all columns?

Comment: Your requirement is inscrutably explained — you will need to explain what you are doing more clearly.  It seems like you might want to output the sum of columns 2 and 3 for rows with column 1 containing values less than 60.  When you come across a row with a value of 60 or more in column 1, print the sums for the previous rows and reset the totals, and print the row read in.  At the end of file, print the sums for the previous rows.  Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: Jonathan Leffler thank you this is exactly what I'd like to have

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '($1<60){sumc2+=$2;sumc3+=$3} ($1>=60){print sumc2, sumc3; sumc2=sumc3=0;print} END{print sumc2, sumc3}' sample.csv
```

`sumc2` and `sumc3` are sum of column2 and sum of column3 respectively. 
When column1 <60, keep sum up the columns; once column1 is >=60, print the summed values, reset them and print the current input.

Since you didn't provide the complete desired output, I print below format

Output:

```
171 236
60     90   90
300 500
```

Comment: you can remove BEGIN block without loss of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '
  {
    if($1<60){
      sum_b+=$2;
      sum_c+=$3;
      print $0
    } else {
      print $1,$2,$3,sum_b,sum_c;
      sum_b=0;
      sum_c=0
    }
  }
  END {
    print"","","",sum_b,sum_c
  }
' datafile
0 56 56
0 45 100
0 70 80
60 90 90 171 236
0 100 200
0.1 200 300
   300 500
```